# How to convert RDD of JSONs to Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have an RDD that has been created from some JSON, each record in the RDD contains key/value pairs. My RDD looks like:

```
myRdd.foreach(println)
```

```
{"sequence":89,"id":8697344444103393,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527636408955},1],
{"sequence":153,"id":8697389197662617,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637852762},1],
{"sequence":155,"id":8697389381205360,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637858607},1],
{"sequence":136,"id":8697374208897843,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637405129},1],
{"sequence":189,"id":8697413135394406,"trackingInfo":{"row":0,"trackId":14272744,"requestId":"284929d9-6147-4924-a19f-4a308730354c-3348447","rank":0,"videoId":80075830,"location":"PostPlay\/Next"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527638558756},1],
{"sequence":130,"id":8697373887446384,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637394083}]
```

I would to convert each record to a row in a spark dataframe, the nested fields in trackingInfo should be there own columns and the `type` list should be its own column also.

So far I've tired to split it using a case class :

```
case class Event(
    sequence: String, 
    id: String, 
    trackingInfo:String,
    location:String, 
    row:String, 
    trackId: String, 
    listrequestId: String, 
    videoId:String, 
    rank: String, 
    requestId: String, 
    `type`:String, 
    time: String)

val dataframeRdd = myRdd.map(line => line.split(",")).
    map(array => Event(
        array(0).split(":")(1),
        array(1).split(":")(1),
        array(2).split(":")(1),
        array(3).split(":")(1),
        array(4).split(":")(1),
        array(5).split(":")(1),
        array(6).split(":")(1),
        array(7).split(":")(1),
        array(8).split(":")(1),
        array(9).split(":")(1),
        array(10).split(":")(1),
        array(11).split(":")(1)
        ))
```

However I keep getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` errors.

What is the best way to do this ? As you can see record number 5 has a slight difference in the ordering of some attributes. Is it possible to parse based on attribute names instead of splitting on "," etc.

I'm using Spark 1.6.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `json rdd` seems to be invalid `jsons`. You need to convert them to valid `jsons` as

```
val validJsonRdd = myRdd.map(x => x.replace(",1],", ",").replace("}]", "}"))
```

then you can use the `sqlContext` to read the valid `rdd` `jsons` into a `dataframe` as

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(validJsonRdd)
```

which should give you dataframe ( i used the invalid json you provided in the question)

```
+----------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|id              |sequence|time        |trackingInfo                                                                                                                             |type                   |
+----------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|8697344444103393|89      |527636408955|[cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585,Browse,0,ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171,0,14170286,80000778]|[Play, Action, Session]|
|8697389197662617|153     |527637852762|[cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585,Browse,0,ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171,0,14170286,80000778]|[Play, Action, Session]|
|8697389381205360|155     |527637858607|[cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585,Browse,0,ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171,0,14170286,80000778]|[Play, Action, Session]|
|8697374208897843|136     |527637405129|[cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585,Browse,0,ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171,0,14170286,80000778]|[Play, Action, Session]|
|8697413135394406|189     |527638558756|[null,PostPlay/Next,0,284929d9-6147-4924-a19f-4a308730354c-3348447,0,14272744,80075830]                                                  |[Play, Action, Session]|
|8697373887446384|130     |527637394083|[cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585,Browse,0,ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171,0,14170286,80000778]|[Play, Action, Session]|
+----------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

and the schema for the dataframe is

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sequence: long (nullable = true)
 |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |-- trackingInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- listId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rank: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- requestId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- row: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- trackId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- videoId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlContext.read.json(myRDD.map(_._2)) to read json into a dataframe